# Excel function to get first word from sentence in other cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Excel: What function can I use to take the all the characters from the beginning to the first '<". I am trying to strip out the first word from A1 and put it into B1

Eg:

```
A1
Toronto<b> is nice
```

I want "Toronto" in the next cell.

Ian

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about something like

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

or

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("<b>",A1)-1)
```

Have a look at [MS Excel: Search Function](http://techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/search.php) and [Excel 2007 LEFT Function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/20070921_left.htm)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to cater to 1-word cell, use this... based upon astander's

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1),A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [exceljet.net](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-word) and works for me:

```
=LEFT(B4,FIND(" ",B4)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1                   A2 
Toronto<b> is nice   =LEFT(A1,(FIND("<",A1,1)-1))
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct but the forumla in A2 will work for you,

Answer (score -1):

Generic solution extracting the first "***n***" words of ***refcell*** string into a new string of "***x***" number of characters

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(***refcell***&" "," ",REPT(" ",***x***),***n***),***x***)
```

Assuming A1 has text string to extract, the 1st word extracted to a 15 character result

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",15),1),15)
```

This would result in "Toronto" being returned to a 15 character string.  1st 2 words extracted to a 30 character result

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",30),2),30)
```

would result in "Toronto is" being returned to a 30 character string

Comment: @rayryeng - thanks for your format updates.  This answer is beyond what the question asked, but I find useful in a number of more complex situations.

Comment: No problem at all. BTW, I did not downvote. I'm not sure who that was.

Comment: Here is a cool example of how I use the generic solution for extracting 3 words.    Given a full timestamp text string in cell B3 = September 15, 2016 1:51:46 PM GMT-07:00,  I can extract the date into Excel internal format in one single command    =DATEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B3 & " "," ",REPT(" ",20),3),20))      This will extrtact the date portion of the timestamp using the first 3 words and then in turn convert that value into Excel internal date format.   :)