# excel first word from cells in other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I extract the first word of a number of different cells and have each of the first words show together in one other cell separated by comma?

e.g. A1 shows "Firstname1 Lastname1", A2 shows "Firstname2 Lastname2", A3 shows "Firstname3 Lastname3",

I need a formula allowing me to show the following in cell D2 "Firstname1, Firstname2, Firstname3"

I found this solution, which gives me the first word of one cell and shows it in another cell but I don't know how to get the first word of a number of cells and show them all coma separated in another cell

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

[Excel function to get first word from sentence in other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264315/excel-function-to-get-first-word-from-sentence-in-other-cell)

Thanks!

Comment: VBA would probably be more efficient here. Maybe something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13369195/1578604).

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of `just three cells` you have an Excel range `A1:A100` which has all the names? How would you concatenate in such an instance? `Will you type that long a formula`?

As Jerry suggested, VBA is Apt for this. But what if you do not want to use VBA or long formulas?

See this example. I am taking 10 cells for the sake of explaining.

Let's say the data looks like this.

[image]

Now select the entire column and click on Data~~>Text To Columns

[image]

When you click finish, the output will be like this

[image]

Now in cell say `E4`, type this `=Transpose(A1:A10)`. Replace `A1:A10` with the actual range. However do not press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Press the key <kbd>F9</kbd>. You will see that all the first names are now visible.

[image]

Simply copy that and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Now open Notepad and paste it there.

Next delete the `{` and the `}`

Next manually replace `","` by `,` and you will get what you wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1) &", "&LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)&", "&LEFT(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)-1)

Answer (score 0):

using your current formula, `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)`, you can add the value of subsequent cells to the previous calculation, and build the comma separated values.

in **B1**, we have your original formula, `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)`
in **B2** we concatenate the previous result, and add on the comma and the new word:

```
=B1 & "," & LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)
```

copy this to B3 (and on) and you will slowly see the full list getting created.

The last value is the one you want, so, in C1, put the formula

```
=OFFSET(B1,COUNTA(B:B)-1,0)
```

*(and hide column B so it looks better)*