# How to make left function stop after a blank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to only extract the first word or continuous string using the left function?

Currently I have my left function set to 70 letters but that captures more than what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel function to get first word from sentence in other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264315/excel-function-to-get-first-word-from-sentence-in-other-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **C2**, in **D2** enter:

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: ah, he meant formula, withdrawing my answer,